# Azure Active Directory and Microsoft Dynamic 365 finance & operation authentication token issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I want to use web API for the MicroSoft Dynamic 365 Finance and Operation, as per the their guide line I have created/registered app in the Azure Active Directory and try to generate Access Toke as per below using the Postman, but getting issue of scope :

**Error:** AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://api.financials.dynamics.com/ is not valid. The scope format is invalid. Scope must be in a valid URI form https://example/scope or a valid Guid ..

**Postman get access token data**

**Auth URL :** https://login.microsoftonline.com/coromed.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

**Access Tocken URL :** https://login.microsoftonline.com/coromed.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

**Client id =** [Our Client ID]

**Client Secret** = [hsdhjkfhsjkdhfjkwshdjkfhsjkdhfjsdjhfgwjdsgfwegew]

**Scope** = https%3A%2F%2Fapi.financials.dynamics.com%2F

**Grant Type** = Autorization Code

Which parameter and its format have to use in scope field ?

Below is snapshot :

[image]

[image]

Please help to solve issue and what should we have add in Sope value.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try these scopes please ? "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyGiretti, but its for the graph, we are looking for the read/write the products/Items/customer/order of Dynamic 365 Finance & operations.

Comment: I know unwanted to know if you have the same errror message with

Comment: Same error here. The frustrating part is that it says `Scope must be a valid URI`, and the same message echoes what you passed: a valid URI!